# Why is 近两年来，这些志愿者积极投入到各项环保活动 ungrammatical?

Tags: grammar

> 近两年来，这些志愿者积极投入到各项环保活动。
> <sub>HSK6 H61007</sub>

The above is given as an ungrammatical sentence, but it's not clear to me why.  There are two inconsistent [HiNative corrections](https://hinative.com/ru/questions/17047420):

> **两年来**，这些志愿者积极投入到各项环保活动。
> 近两年来，这些志愿者积极**参与到**各项环保活动**中**。

If I were to guess, I'd say 投入到 should just be 投入 (since the 入 already carries the meaning of 到).

**Question**: Why is 近两年来,这些志愿者积极投入到各项环保活动 ungrammatical?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As a native speaker, I would say"投入到各项环保活动**中**"。
the structure might be verb+rusult complement……中/里.
e.g.把衣服放到洗衣机里,放 is the verb,到 is the result complement to modify 放，里 is the second result complement to complete 到；two more examples:把自己沉浸到故事情节里；把钱投到股市里。
In the structure above, both 中 and 里 mean "in/within", they seem kind of redundant from the perspective of English grammar, but in Chinese, it is a commonly used "sandwich pattern" which means "within (something or progress)."
without 里/中, native speakers feel like it's an incomplete sentence.
As for the verb, whether to use 投入 or 参与，that doesn't matter much in this context.However, they have little difference. you can 投入 money, time, enthusiasm or attention,but if you say  参与，means that you indeed get yourself involved in some events or you did something there.

Comment: I agree. More comment on the verb: 参与 is a neutral participation, while 投入 is devoted. "投入到各项环保活动" definitely feels incomplete, but I don't know why "进入到积云塔" (picked from the corpus) feels complete.

Comment: 摩察导致边界层顶的上升运动，使低层气流上升到积云塔中，或者低层具有源源不断的空气和水汽质量流进入到积云塔。 Perhaps it's a feature of the verb 进入. Another example could 进入到一个新的阶段.

Comment: i might need more context about "进入到积云塔".But generally it's kind of weird to say 进入"到"积云塔 alone,到 is redundant here. if it says 进入积云塔，it feels better and more natural, and i might expect another clause after it, like 我看到了一张桌子。 however, I wouldn't say 进入到积云塔 is very wrong, some people would like to add some redundant complement words like 到 after verbs. some colloquial way to say" 给到你一张优惠券”，the speaker wants to convey the feeling of gaining by adding 到 after the verb 给。I guess it's the same logic in 进入到积云塔。

Comment: oh, in that context, it's alright

Answer (score 3):

I think it just missed a position word 中.

Usually we say 投入到水***里***, not 投入到水. By the same token, the original sentence can be corrected as 这些志愿者积极投入到各项环保活动***中***.

Answer (score 1):

I think the sentences below are grammatically correct, complete, and acceptable.

近两年来，这些志愿者**都**积极**的**投入到各项环保活动**中**。

近两年来，这些志愿者**都**积极**的參與**各项环保活动。

In the first sentence, "中" echos "到", the sentence should be considered correct without the two words:

- 近两年来，这些志愿者**都**积极**的**投入各项环保活动。

Answer (score 0):

> When 投入 mean "to deploy", it requires an object

Example:

- 这些志愿者(被)积极(投入到)各项环保活动(中)。 -- 志愿者 is the object to be deployed

> Missing rusult complement [Verb] + [到] + object [中]

被投入(到)各项环保活动 -->被投入(到)各项环保活动(中)

Answer (score -1):

I think it is a case of wrong usage of words / phrases rather than being ungrammatical.

If I were to pick between the two corrections, I'll go for the second one:-

近两年来，这些志愿者积极参与到各项环保活动中。

First, there is nothing wrong with 近两年来.

Second, 投入 is a completely wrong choice of words because this phrase means "investment", as in investment in stocks & shares. You don't "invest" in "environmental protection", unless the sentence includes investing some money or even time in this regard.

In the sentence however both money and time are absent, it is 活动, "activities", which you don't "invest in", but as we see below, you "participate in"

Therefore, 参与到, "to take part in" / "to participate" is appropriate.

The "中" wraps up the sentence, to indicates participation "in" some activity.

Comment: 投入 can mean "deploy" - 志愿者(volunteer )-投身于(dedicate to); 投入( invest/ deploy)- 人材 
Volunteer - ; invest - talents