# What are the answers to the HSK6 语病 ("faulty wording") questions on the 22 publicly available HSK6 exams?

Tags: grammar, hsk

There are [22 publicly available HSK6 exams](https://archive.org/details/elsey_HSK6).  Since I'm studying this topic for my upcoming exam, I might as well self-answer the question...

**Question**: What are the answers to the HSK6 语病 ("faulty wording") questions on the 22 publicly available HSK6 exams?

This section is notoriously hard, with [some students simply blindly guessing](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/q/39715/8099) and even [native speakers having trouble](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/q/5479/2795).  The current explanations are scattered all over the Internet, and they often contradict one another.  It would be worthwhile having a single location with all the correct justifications.

I categorized the 220 语病 answers (10 per test paper) as follows:

- [Incorrect word choice](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/a/50544/8099) (49)
- [Unwanted word(s)](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/a/50546/8099) (36)
- [Incorrect word order](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/a/50539/8099) (29)
- [Missing word(s)](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/a/50545/8099) (25)
- [Redundancy](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/a/50542/8099) (19)
- [Subject mismatch](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/a/50540/8099) (17)
- [Other](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/a/50547/8099)

  - Self-contradictory (9)
  - Double negative (5)
  - Overworked object (2)
  - Subject-verb-object misuse (3)
  - No subject (8)
  - Grammar misuse (18)

(Checksum: [49+36+29+25+19+17+(9+5+2+3+8+18)](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=49%2B36%2B29%2B25%2B19%2B17%2B%289%2B5%2B2%2B3%2B8%2B18%29) = 220)

Thanks to Reddit user Rethliopuks, [who also adds](https://www.reddit.com/r/ChineseLanguage/comments/y13uym/comment/irwjqw7/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3) (October 2022):

> Speaking as linguist specialising in Mandarin syntax. Most of them are pretty clear-cut ungrammatical, but a few actually are fine (native speakers find no problems in them), they're just regarded wrong prescriptively. Which means you see and hear them, but the standardisers of the language disapprove of them, so in super proper documents it is better to avoid them, and for test purposes you should consider them "wrong".

Comment: I think you should list the ones that you are in doubt only, or have questions about. It is way too heavy a topic for this forum.

Comment: It's meant to be a reference for people (like me) who are studying this.  There's only a handful I'm unsure about, which I can ask about separately.

Comment: This may or may not be on topic, but as it stands @r13 is right and you should gather some consensus on [meta](https://chinese.meta.stackexchange.com/) before posting this.

Comment: [Meta post](https://chinese.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1911/8099) created.

Comment: If the reader is after further 语病 questions, [here](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/q/52489/8099) are some from a mock exam.

Answer (score 1):

## Missing word(s)

| Exam | Q<sup>n</sup> | Ans. | Original snippet with error highlighted | Comments |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| H61000 | 51 | D | 他除了班里和学生会的工作外，还**承担**了广播站的**主持人**。 | Correction: 承担……主持人工作 ([ref.](https://zhidao.baidu.com/question/398968836.html)) |
| H61000 | 58 | C | **现代社会要求人们**思想敏锐，**探索精神和创新能力**，对自然、社会和人生具有更深刻的思考和认识。 | Error: missing verb 具备 connecting 人们 to 能力 ([ref.](https://zhidao.baidu.com/question/530133687.html)) |
| H61001 | 56 | A | 有些电脑设计得很小巧，甚至可以**放**一个很薄的文件袋里。 | Correction: 放在 ([ref.](https://zh.hinative.com/questions/17025909)) or 放进 ([ref.](https://zh.hinative.com/questions/17025909)) |
| H61001 | 58 | C | 父亲经常说，美术教育的目的，**是学生**对每一种平凡的事物，都能有美的感触，都能欣赏到美。 | Correction: 是让学生……; [ref.](https://zh.hinative.com/questions/17025909) changes it to 是为了让学生…… |
| H61002 | 60 | D | 南京，古称金陵，已有近2500年的历史。**她**既有自然山水之胜，又有历史文物之雅，兼具古今文明的园林化**城市**。 | Correction: add 是 before 兼具 to connect 她……城市 (ref. [1](https://zh.hinative.com/questions/17031459) [2](https://blog.daum.net/classical0123/1732)) |
| H61003 | 55 | B | 他这个人除了有点固执之外，还有**不少让人值得佩服**。 | Correction: add 的地方 at the end ([ref.](https://zh.hinative.com/questions/17033653)) |
| H61003 | 60 | D |  | duplicate: H61002 Q.60 |
| H61004 | 53 | B | 语言的使用，**促进了人类的思维**，使得大脑更加发达。 | Error: 促进……思维 is mismatched; should be e.g. 促进了人类思维的发展 ([ref.](https://www.italki.com/post/question-162851)); [ref.](https://zh.hinative.com/questions/17041574) changes it to 使得大脑更加发达 |
| H61004 | 59 | C | 《**富春山居图**》是元朝画家黄公望的作品，以浙江富春江为背景，墨色浓淡干湿并用，极富于变化，是中国**十**大传世名画。 | Error: missing 之一 at the end ([ref.](https://zh.hinative.com/questions/17041574)) |
| H61005 | 54 | C | 一般情况下，**敬酒**一定要充分考虑好敬酒的顺序，分明主次。 | Correction: 敬酒时 ([ref.](https://zh.hinative.com/questions/17313556)) |
| H61005 | 57 | C | 据预测，明年第二季度国际市场的原油日需求量将**减少**250万桶**以内**。 | Correction: 减少到 ([ref.](https://zh.hinative.com/questions/17039445)) [or delete 以内] |
| H61007 | 51 | C | 父亲对我要求特别高，他的全部希望**寄托我身上**。 | Correction: 寄托在我身上 ([ref.](https://zh.hinative.com/questions/17047420)) |
| H61007 | 55 | A | 近两年来，这些志愿者积极**投入到**各项环保活动。 | Correction: needs a 中 or 里 at the end ([ref.](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/q/50520/8099)) |
| H61008 | 57 | A | 故宫旧称紫禁城，是北京最**标志性**的建筑。 | The 性 in 标志性 makes it function as a noun, not an adjective, so it should be e.g. 具有标志性 ([ref.](https://zh.hinative.com/questions/17049071)) |
| H61008 | 58 | C | 周四之前，你们先**把**这个问题**研究**，周四上午，向公司董事会做一个全面的介绍。 | Error: 把……[v.] needs a complement afterwards, e.g. 研究好; [ref.](https://zh.hinative.com/questions/17049071) chooses 研究出来 |
| H61009 | 51 | B | **从地图上**，黄河干流就像一个巨大的“几”字。 | Correction: 从地图上看 ([ref.](https://zh.hinative.com/questions/17052657)) |
| H61111 | 51 | A | 指南针**是**中国古代的**四**大发明。 | Error: missing 之一 at the end ([ref.](https://zh.hinative.com/questions/17057338)) |
| H61219 | 54 | C | 信阳毛尖香气清新，畅销全国，**是**中国**十**大名茶。 | Error: missing 之一 at the end ([ref.](https://hinative.com/ko/questions/17065516)) |
| H61220 | 54 | A | 大自然的许多奥妙是与人生的某些现象**相似之处**的。 | Error: missing e.g. 有; should be e.g. ……具有相似之处的 ([ref.](https://zh.hinative.com/questions/17067100)) |
| H61220 | 55 | A | **截止**下午5点，入园参观人数已超过15万。 | Correction: 截止到 ([ref.](https://zh.hinative.com/questions/17067100)) |
| H61220 | 57 | D | 春秋时候，越国有个**名字**西施的姑娘，她非常漂亮，一举一动都很动人。 | Correction: 名字叫 or 名字是 ([ref.](https://zh.hinative.com/questions/17067100)) |
| H61220 | 58 | A | 研究表明，和夏天相比，**冬天人们**更容易回到集体之中，从事一些群体性活动的季节。 | Correction: 冬天是人们…… ([ref.](https://zh.hinative.com/questions/17067100)) |
| H61220 | 60 | D | “蝴蝶效应”是指在一个动力系统中，初始条件下微小的变化会**整个系统**带来长期、巨大的连锁反应。 | Correction: 给整个系统 ([ref.](https://zh.hinative.com/questions/17067100)) |
| H61329 | 54 | B | 虽然他们之间有时也**会小矛盾**，但相处得还算融洽。 | Correction: 会有小矛盾 ([ref.](https://zhidao.baidu.com/question/1366316020751247339.html)) |
| H61333 | 56 | A | 他将这次演唱会的门票收入全部**捐献**一家儿童医院。 | Correction: 捐献给 ([ref.](https://zhidao.baidu.com/question/1366316020751247339.html)) |

Answer (score 0):

## Incorrect word order

We can rearrange the words to correct the snippet.

| Exam | Q<sup>n</sup> | Ans. | Original snippet with error highlighted | Comments |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| H61000 | 60 | D | 岳飞是中国南宋时期的英雄，**他率领**岳家军打败敌人**屡次**。后人为了纪念他，在杭州建了一座岳王庙。 | Correction: 他屡次率领…… ([ref.](https://zh.hinative.com/questions/12906719)); 屡次打败 ([ref.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zjHYYA-OywY) see ~19m20s); the important thing is the put 屡次 before a verb |
| H61001 | 52 | A | 天凉了，你要**穿多点儿**衣服。 | Correction: 多穿点儿 ([ref.](https://zh.hinative.com/questions/14128497)); [this is debatable](https://www.jianshu.com/p/2b2cb1f97e5b) |
| H61001 | 55 | B | 18世纪以后，世界人口的增长速度才**加快明显起来**。 | Correction: 明显加快起来 (ref. [1](https://zh.hinative.com/questions/12675551) [2](https://answers.echineselearning.com/questions/2014-07/19/002319383DETLRLEO.html)) |
| H61003 | 59 | D | 怀疑自己，导致我们内心受挫，总是生活在失败的阴影里；怀疑别人，则**缺乏安全感让我们**，总是生活在自己假想的危险中。 | Correction: 让我们缺乏安全感 |
| H61005 | 56 | D | 每个人都需要表露自己的情绪:如喜怒哀乐忧惧等，**尤其孩子**如此。 | Correction: 孩子尤其 ([ref.](https://zh.hinative.com/questions/17039445)) or 尤其是孩子 ([ref.](https://www.italki.com/post/question-162851)) |
| H61006 | 54 | C | **不但他**喜欢京剧脸谱，而且喜欢京剧的各种服饰。 | Correction: 他不但 (ref. [1](https://hinative.com/ko/questions/17044588) [2](https://wdfc.game234.com/q/15007613.html)) |
| H61006 | 56 | A | 你知道，以前我**做过推销员三年**。 | Correction: 做过三年的推销员 ([ref.](https://zh.hinative.com/questions/17292434)) or 以前我做推销员做过三年 ([ref.](https://www.reddit.com/r/ChineseLanguage/comments/y13uym/comment/irwjqw7/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3)) |
| H61008 | 60 | C | **尽管**夏季烈日曝晒，冬季寒风扫荡，**却海洋的温度变化很小**。因此，巨大的海洋就像是天然的“温箱”，是孕育原始生命的“温床”。 | Correction: 海水的温度变化却比较小 ([ref.](https://zh.hinative.com/questions/17049071)); appears [adapted](https://www.sohu.com/a/195866657_390792) from ……任凭夏季烈日曝晒，冬季寒风扫荡，它的温度变化却比较小。 |
| H61009 | 56 | A | 去别人家做客，注意不要**添别人麻烦**。 | Correction: 给别人添麻烦 ([ref.](https://zh.hinative.com/questions/17052657)) |
| H61009 | 60 | D | 当双方的意见僵持不下时，你就应该明白，再这样下去**都没有好处对双方**，争取形成一个双方都能接受的方案是最好的选择。 | Correction: 对双方都没有好处 ([ref.](https://zh.hinative.com/questions/17052657)) |
| H61110 | 58 | C | 宽容是一种为人处世的哲学。只有宽容他人的过错，**与人才能**建立起良好的人际关系，赢得别人的钦佩与尊敬。 | Correction: 才能与人 ([ref.](https://zh.hinative.com/questions/17056178)) |
| H61111 | 58 | D | 许多人一生都在等待一个可以改变他命运的机会。事实上，机会无所不在，而关键在于，当机会出现时，你**已经是否**准备好了。 | Correction: 是否已经 ([ref.](https://zh.hinative.com/questions/17057338)) |
| H61219 | 51 | B | 和观察新事物比起来，**去观察用新的眼光**更重要。 | Correction: 用新的眼光去观察 ([ref.](https://zh.hinative.com/questions/17065516)) |
| H61218 | 55 | D | 他很有魅力，我每次看到他的时候**都保持着他**那独特的微笑。 | Correction: 他都保持着 ([ref.](https://zh.hinative.com/questions/17063290)) |
| H61218 | 56 | D | 运动前要做好准备活动，特别是剧烈运动前要让膝关节**一定**充分活动。 | Correction: 一定 should be before 要 ([ref.](https://zh.hinative.com/questions/17063290)) |
| H61220 | 52 | C | 请把电视机的声音开**一点儿小**，不要打扰到其他人。 | Correction: 小一点儿 ([ref.](https://zh.hinative.com/questions/17067100)) |
| H61220 | 56 | C | 现在放弃等于半途而废，这意味着我们**所做的努力之前**都白费了。 | Correction: 之前所做的努力 ([ref.](https://zh.hinative.com/questions/17067100)) |
| H61221 | 52 | B | 我父亲热情好客，家里经常**来客人很多**。 | Correction: 来很多客人 ([ref.](https://zh.hinative.com/questions/17059530)) |
| H61221 | 59 | B | 人生就是一场旅行，不在乎目的地，**在乎的而是**沿途的风景以及看风景的心情。 | Correction: 而在乎的是 ([ref.](https://zh.hinative.com/questions/17059530)) |
| H61327 | 58 | B | 双面绣《猫》是苏绣的代表作之一，不管从正面看还是从反面看，**小猫的神态都能看到调皮、活泼**。 | Correction: 都能看到小猫调皮、活泼的神态 ([ref.](https://zh.hinative.com/questions/17070856)) |
| H61327 | 60 | D | 进化论的一个**观点基本**是：在生物进化过程中，适应自然环境的物种得以生存下来，不适应的就被淘汰，这就是所谓的“优胜劣汰，适者生存”。 | Correction: 基本观点 （[ref.](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/q/54250/8099)) |
| H61328 | 53 | C | 离开家乡许多年了，没想到这里**翻天覆地发生了变化**。 | Correction: 发生了翻天覆地的变化 (ref. [1](https://www.reddit.com/r/ChineseLanguage/comments/qi5r2v/does_anyone_know_why_this_sentence_is_wrong/) [2](https://blog.daum.net/classical0123/1747)) |
| H61328 | 57 | D | 第二天，世界各大报纸都**做了详细报道对这起震惊国际体坛的事件**。 | Correction: 对这起震惊国际体坛的事件做了详细报道 ([ref.](https://zh.hinative.com/questions/20074086)) |
| H61329 | 53 | B | 专家建议，每天佩戴隐形眼镜的时间**超过8小时不宜**。 | Correction: 不宜超过8小时; appears [adapted](https://health.sohu.com/20070803/n251400625.shtml) from 总的来说，每天戴隐形眼镜的时间不宜超过8小时…… |
| H61330 | 53 | C | 寂寞是一块儿试金石，可以试出一个人意志**坚韧是否**。 | Correction: 是否坚韧; appears [adapted](http://blog.sina.com.cn/s/blog_b885b3c40101nxys.html) from 寂寞是一块试金石，可以试出一个人意志是否坚韧…… |
| H61332 | 51 | B | 保持年轻的**之一秘诀**是拥有健康的心态。 | Correction: 秘诀之一 ([ref.](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/a/39719/8099)) |
| H61332 | 55 | A | 青蛙因经常吃**害虫农田里的**而被人们称为“庄稼的保护神”。 | Correction: 农田里的害虫 ([ref.](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/a/39719/8099)) |
| H61333 | 53 | C | 感谢您的来电，请您稍后**进行评价对本次服务**，谢谢。 | Correction: 对本次服务进行评价; appears [adapted](https://hrss.suzhou.gov.cn/jsszhrss/yxfwal/202201/9666687a5dbd4a2f831da0ac2b5d990c.shtml) from 不客气的，感谢您的来电，稍后请对本次服务进行评价再见。 |
| H61333 | 59 | D | “口头禅”是一个人的习惯用语。它的形成跟使用者的性格、生活经历**有关系很大**，可以算是一个人的标志。 | Correction: 有很大的关系 |

Answer (score 0):

## Subject mismatch

The intended subject is not the actual subject.

| Exam | Q<sup>n</sup> | Ans. | Original snippet with error highlighted | Comments |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| H61001 | 57 | C | **人们**居住在地球上，**是**一块天然的**大磁体**，在南北两极有两个磁极。 | Correction: e.g. add 地球 before 是 ([ref.](https://zh.hinative.com/questions/17025909)) |
| H61003 | 58 | D | 实践表明，一个国家森林的**覆盖率**达到全国总面积30%以上，或者**分布均匀**时，就不会发生较大的风沙旱涝等自然灾害。 | Error: the subject is coverage rate (覆盖率) which cannot distribute evenly (分布均匀); need to add 森林 after 或者 ([ref.](https://nihao79.com/upload/books/1618548742_sub.pdf) p.157), or "move the 的. 一个国家的森林覆盖率 makes it ok" ([ref.](https://www.reddit.com/r/ChineseLanguage/comments/y13uym/comment/irwjqw7/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3)); online there is a variety of other explanations, such as changing 或者 to 且 ([ref.](https://zh.hinative.com/questions/17033653)) or 并且 ([ref.](https://answers.echineselearning.com/questions/2017-06/30/231341530RKBYWMZC.html)), and [ref.](http://blog.sina.com.cn/s/blog_945207c00101fi5j.html) says 的 should be deleted from 森林的覆盖率 |
| H61004 | 54 | D | **他的见解**独到而且深刻，常应邀到许多高校**发表演讲**，深受学生欢迎。 | Error: the subject is his opinions (他的见解) because they're described as original (独到) and deep (深刻), but opinions cannot give speeches (发表演讲) |
| H61004 | 58 | D |  | duplicate: H61003 Q.58 |
| H61005 | 51 | A | 7月的内蒙古**草原**，**是**一个美丽的**季节**。 | Correction: change the first clause to 内蒙古草原的7月 so that 7月 is the subject ([ref.](https://zh.hinative.com/questions/17039445)) |
| H61005 | 58 | A | 在她的心目中，**童年**跟大自然**相处**的那段日子是自己受过的最好的艺术教育。 | Error: the subject childhood (童年) cannot get in contact (相处) with nature (大自然); should add 她 after 童年 to change the subject to 她 ([ref.](https://zhidao.baidu.com/question/434923176.html?sort=6)) |
| H61006 | 55 | C | 这个地区的粮食**总产量**，除了供给本地区外，还**运送**给其他地区。 | Error: subject should be 粮食 not 总产量; delete 总产量 ([ref.](https://zh.hinative.com/questions/17044588)) |
| H61008 | 53 | B | 二十四**节气是**中国古代制定的一种用来指导农业生产的补充**历法**。 | Note: The official answer is C, but this is a mistake |
| H61009 | 52 | B | 这个月公司的**业绩是**今年以来业绩中最好的**一个月**。 | Correction: delete 一个月 ([ref.](https://zh.hinative.com/questions/17052657)) |
| H61110 | 55 | B | 这本杂志的**对象**，主要是**面向**中国留学生及其他汉语爱好者。 | Correction: delete 的对象 ([ref.](https://zh.hinative.com/questions/17056178)) to change the subject to 这本杂志 |
| H61110 | 60 | B | **天气的变化**，直接影响着动物的生活，往往能及时**察觉到**天气的变化，并预先做好相应的准备。 | Correction: add 一些感觉敏锐的动物 before 往往 to make it the subject starting from the second clause. Appears [adapted](https://zhidao.baidu.com/question/346461446.html) from 展开全部天气的变化，直接影响着动物的生活。一些感觉敏锐的动物，往往能及时察觉到天气的变化，预先做好准备。 |
| H61218 | 52 | B | **中国**是扇子的故乡，**在中国**有着悠久的历史。 | Correction: add 扇子 before 在中国 ([ref.](https://zh.hinative.com/questions/17063290)) |
| H61218 | 53 | D | 这一天的**活动**是同学们这段时间最紧张、最愉快也是最有意义的**一天**。 | Correction: delete 的活动 ([ref.](https://zh.hinative.com/questions/17063290)) |
| H61328 | 56 | C | 雨花石天然细腻的**花纹**，玲珑剔透的质感，**被誉为“石中皇后”**。 | Correction: it should begin 雨花石有…… ([ref.](https://blog.daum.net/classical0123/1747)) |
| H61329 | 51 | C | 经过治疗，儿子的**病**已经**恢复了健康**。 | Correction: delete 的病 to make 儿子 the subject |
| H61329 | 57 | A | 《**雨巷**》是戴望舒的成名作，因此**获得了“雨巷诗人”的称号**。 | Appears [adapted](https://zhidao.baidu.com/question/2145997189362905508.html) from 《雨巷》是戴望舒的成名作，诗人因此获得“雨巷诗人”的称号。 |
| H61330 | 55 | B | 专家建议，求职者谨慎的**态度**找工作是对的，但也不可过于挑剔。 | Correction: add e.g. 抱着 before 谨慎 to change the subject to 求职者 ([ref.](https://answers.echineselearning.com/questions/2014-07/07/235151865GZEITNBX.html)) |

Answer (score 0):

## Redundancy

Something is repeated, leading to an error.

| Exam | Q<sup>n</sup> | Ans. | Original snippet with error highlighted | Comments |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| H61000 | 54 | A | 终于看到了大熊猫，儿子显得**特别**兴奋**极了**。 | ([ref.](https://zh.hinative.com/questions/12906626)) |
| H61000 | 56 | D | 中国古代地域辽阔，民族众多，历史上形成的传统节日**多达到**数百个。 | either 多达 vs. 达到 ([ref.](https://zh.hinative.com/questions/12906645)) |
| H61000 | 59 | C | 不知不觉中，她已经长成了一个**十分亭亭玉立**的姑娘，粗劣的饮食和严酷的生活并没有影响她。 | ([ref.](https://zhidao.baidu.com/question/280808031.html)); ([ref.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zjHYYA-OywY) see ~17m20s) |
| H61001 | 54 | C | 两个人在一起，遇到事至少可以**商量商量一下**，总比一个人好。 | Correction: 商量商量 or 商量一下 ([ref.](https://zh.hinative.com/questions/17025909)) |
| H61001 | 59 | D | 作为一名翻译工作者，**一方面要**努力学好外语，**一方面要**学好本民族语言**也是非常重要的**，两者缺一不可。 | ([ref.](https://zh.hinative.com/questions/17025909)) |
| H61002 | 54 | A | 妈妈把茶几擦**得一尘不染得干净**。 | Correction: delete 得一尘不染 or 得干净 ([ref.](https://zh.hinative.com/questions/17031459)) |
| H61002 | 59 | D |  | duplicate: H61001 Q.59 |
| H61005 | 59 | C | 卷心菜可以说是所有的蔬菜中最为古老的一种，我们知道古时候的人就**已经很久以前一直**在吃它了。 | ([ref.](https://www.italki.com/post/question-162851)) |
| H61006 | 60 | C | 昨天下午，温州市瓦市小学的1000多名学生**十分兴高采烈**地参加了学校举行的“包粽子——感受端午节民族传统文化”实践活动。 | ([ref.](https://zh.hinative.com/questions/17044588)) |
| H61007 | 52 | B | 他们昨晚刚办了一个生日宴会，所以屋子里显得**很乱糟糟**的。 | Correction: delete 很 ([ref.](https://zh.hinative.com/questions/17047420)) |
| H61219 | 53 | A | 他长得**很身强力壮**，个子**大概**在一米八五**左右**。 | 大概……左右 is arguably an error due to redundancy ([ref.](http://t.pae.baidu.com/s?s=bai-ip3jdm)); [ref.](https://zh.hinative.com/questions/17065516) instead highlighted the redundancy in 很身强力壮 |
| H61219 | 58 | A | 花生含脂肪较多，人体对其消化吸收缓慢，大量生吃会**引起产生**消化不良。 | ([ref.](https://hinative.com/ko/questions/17065516)) |
| H61220 | 51 | B | 雨下得非常大，他身上的衣服**基本上完全**湿透了。 | "I actually think this is a case of redundancy plus contradiction. You can say one of 基本上全湿了, 基本上湿透了, and 完全湿透了. The first two mean "basically all wet", and the third means "thoroughly wet" and is emphatic. So you can't mix all three together." ([ref.](https://www.reddit.com/r/ChineseLanguage/comments/y13uym/comment/irwjqw7/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3)); ([ref.](https://zh.hinative.com/questions/17067100)) |
| H61220 | 53 | C | 祖冲之**从小很早**就对天文学和数学产生了浓厚的兴趣。 | ([ref.](https://zh.hinative.com/questions/17067100)) |
| H61218 | 60 | B | 所有物体之间都有引力，而一个物体的质量**越大**，它对别的物体的引力就会**越来越大**。 | Correction: 越来越大 should just be 越大 |
| H61328 | 60 | D | 孔子**之所以**提倡“因材施教”的**原因**是**因为**每个人的想法和接受能力都不同，所以，老师应根据学生的特点，有针对性地教学。 | Correction: delete 的原因 (ref. [1](https://www.italki.com/post/question-504642), [2](https://blog.daum.net/classical0123/1747)) |
| H61330 | 59 | B | 女人似乎天生就是感性动物，她们对色彩、形状、声音的敏感度普遍**高于**男性**之上**。 | Appears [adapted](https://acc.pconline.com.cn/346/3465081_all.html) from 女人天生就是感性动物。她们对色彩、形状、声音的敏感度普遍高于男性。 |
| H61332 | 54 | B | **任何每一个**障碍，都有可能成为一个超越自我的契机。 | ([ref.](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/a/39719/8099)) |
| H61333 | 58 | A | 新春佳节，**每个家家户户**张贴大红春联，给节日增添了不少欢乐祥和的气氛。 | Correction: delete 每个; appears [adapted](https://www.ltncg.com/info/%E6%98%A5%E8%81%94%E7%BB%99%E8%8A%82%E6%97%A5%E5%A2%9E%E6%B7%BB%E4%BA%86%E6%B0%94%E6%B0%9B%E6%89%A9%E5%8F%A5.html) from 新春佳节，家家户户张贴大红春联，给节日增添了不少欢乐祥和的气氛。 |

Answer (score 0):

## Incorrect word choice

| Exam | Q<sup>n</sup> | Ans. | Original snippet with error highlighted | Comments |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| H61000 | 57 | D | 报纸一般只有一期创刊号，由于它重要**然而**数量有限，因此最有升值潜力。 | Correction: 而且 ([ref.](https://zhidao.baidu.com/question/398980347.html)); 并且 ([ref.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zjHYYA-OywY) see ~15m20s) |
| H61001 | 60 | D | 大禹治水的故事家喻户晓，但人们多是把大禹看做一个治水的英雄，实际上大禹最大的**功能**是，他是中国第一个民族国家——夏王朝的奠基人。 | Correction: 成就, 功劳, 功绩, etc.; [ref.](https://zh.hinative.com/questions/19315938) edits it to say 实际上大禹最大的功绩是中国第一个国家 (saying 成功 should either be 功绩 or 功劳) |
| H61002 | 55 | C | 由于自然资源匮乏，**该个**国家的主要工业原料均依赖进口。 | Correction: 这个 or 该 ([ref.](https://zh.hinative.com/questions/17031459)) |
| H61002 | 56 | A | 生活是一**把**镜子，你对它微笑，它也对你微笑。 | Correction: 面 ([ref.](https://zh.hinative.com/questions/17031459)) |
| H61002 | 58 | B | 报告说，该公司第四季度赢利达18.6亿元，**十分**超出了分析人士此前的预期。 | Correction: 大大 or 远远, or just delete 十分 ([ref.](https://zh.hinative.com/questions/17031459)) |
| H61003 | 52 | D | “地球村”之所以能成为现实，主要**出于**互联网技术的迅猛发展。 | Correction: 由于 ([ref.](https://zh.hinative.com/questions/17033653)) |
| H61004 | 52 | C | 电影的发明，让人们第一次可以真实地**实现**活动的生活场景。 | Correction: 重现 (my teacher's correction); [ref.](https://www.italki.com/post/question-162851) gives 再现; [ref.](https://zh.hinative.com/questions/17041574) changes the last part to ……实现生活场景的活动 |
| H61006 | 53 | A | **有没有**坚定的意志，是一个人在事业上**能够**取得成功的关键。 | Correction: change 有没有 to 有 or change 能够 to 能否 ([ref.](https://zh.hinative.com/questions/17292434)) |
| H61006 | 59 | A | 互联网的应用给我们的生活带来了巨大的变化，这些变化**既有**正面的**也是**负面的。 | Correction: 既有……也有…… ([ref.](https://zh.hinative.com/questions/17044588)) |
| H61007 | 57 | D | “胡思乱想”**有助于**消除工作、生活中的紧张疲劳与放松身心**的作用**。 | Correction: 有……的作用; [ref.](https://zh.hinative.com/questions/17047420) changes the last part to ……并且能放松身心; appears [adapted](http://health.ifeng.com/psychology/yangsheng/detail_2010_11/30/3275410_0.shtml) from “胡思乱想”有助于消除工作、生活中的紧张疲劳，起到放松身心的作用。 |
| H61007 | 58 | D | 随着人们环保意识的提高，越来越多的人在购买家电产品时，把节能**做**重要的衡量标准，绿色家电成为新的时尚选择。 | Correction: 做为 ([ref.](https://zh.hinative.com/questions/17047420)) |
| H61007 | 60 | B | 我觉得这篇文章已经很不错了，但还存在一些缺点，**只有**好好修改修改，并把内容充实一下，那就更好了。 | Correction: 如果 ([ref.](https://zh.hinative.com/questions/17052657)) or 只要 |
| H61008 | 51 | B | **关于**母亲的身体健康，他一直很关心。 | Correction: 对于; [ref.](https://zh.hinative.com/questions/17049071) rephrases it to 他一直很关心母亲的身体健康 |
| H61008 | 52 | D | 我们大约30多年**不**见面了，但是在机场我还是一眼就认出她来了。 | Correction: 没 ([ref.](https://zh.hinative.com/questions/17049071)) |
| H61008 | 55 | C | 中国民间传说**数量众大**，内容丰富，而且充满艺术魅力。 | Correction: 数量众多 ([ref.](https://zh.hinative.com/questions/17049071)) |
| H61009 | 58 | B | 我们应该以一颗平常心来**解决**可能不很理想的**现实**，而用一颗进取心去开创美好的未来。 | Correction: 解决 should be e.g. 接受 |
| H61009 | 59 | A |  | duplicate: H61006 Q.59 |
| H61110 | 54 | C | 放心吧，你的事就是我的事，我一定会**尽量**的，下星期三我给你答复。 | Error: 尽量 needs to take an object; should be 尽力 or merged into 尽量在下周三给你答复 ([ref.](https://zh.hinative.com/questions/17056178)) |
| H61110 | 56 | B | 时间是**治理**心灵创伤的大师，但绝不是解决问题的高手。 | Correction: 治疗 ([ref.](https://zh.hinative.com/questions/17056178)) |
| H61111 | 55 | C | 这是我同事小李的女儿，**不仅**年纪小，**而且**非常懂事。 | Correction: 虽然……但是…… ([ref.](https://zh.hinative.com/questions/17057338)) |
| H61111 | 56 | A | 因为身上没带多少钱，所以他今天在书店里只买了**两本书籍**。 | Correction: 两本书 ([ref.](https://zh.hinative.com/questions/17057338)) |
| H61218 | 51 | D | 顾虑太多，犹豫不决，就容易**把**机会从手中溜走。 | There are multiple ways of fixing this, such as changing 把 to 让 ([ref.](https://zh.hinative.com/questions/17063290)) or changing it to ……机会就容易从手中溜走 ([ref.](https://zh.hinative.com/questions/18788781)) |
| H61218 | 58 | A | 吐鲁番地处新疆天山东部的山间盆地，干燥少雨,日照充足,这里**生长**的水果格外甜蜜。 | Correction: 出产 (my teacher's correction)；甜蜜 also could be 甜 ([ref.](https://zh.hinative.com/questions/17063290)) |
| H61218 | 59 | D | 宝宝的口味跟成人的口味有着很大的差异，**于是**给宝宝烹调食物时一定要符合他的口味，做到色香味俱全，并且要经常花样翻新。 | Correction: ([ref.](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/q/50597/8099)) "于是 is followed by an *advice*, which it can't" ([ref.](https://www.reddit.com/r/ChineseLanguage/comments/y13uym/comment/irwjqw7/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3)); 所以 ([ref.](https://zh.hinative.com/questions/17063290)); appears [adapted](http://baby.sina.com.cn/edu/06/2410/150819501.shtml) from 宝宝的口味跟成人的口味有着很大的差异，因此，给宝宝烹调食物时一定要符合他的口味，做到色香味俱全，并且要经常花样翻新。 |
| H61219 | 59 | D | “五岳归来不看山，黄山归来不看岳。”黄山是天下名山中的极品，磅礴的日出、华丽的晚霞、壮观的云海，都能**送给**你无与伦比的享受。 | Correction: 带给; appears [adapted](http://www.moongui.com/gonglue/57.html) from “五岳归来不看山，黄山归来不看岳”，黄山是天下名山中的极品，磅礴的日出、华丽的晚霞、壮观的云海、奇异的佛光，不经意间，这些奇观异景就可能出现在您眼前，带给您无与伦比的感受。 |
| H61220 | 59 | D | 伟人之所以伟大，是因为当他与别人共处逆境时，别人已经失去了信心，**何况**他却下定决心要实现自己的目标。 | Correction: 但是 ([ref.](https://zh.hinative.com/questions/17067100)) |
| H61221 | 53 | C | 先行一步，也许是冒险，**所以**谁敢说冒险不是一种成功的契机？ | Correction: 但是 ([ref.](https://zh.hinative.com/questions/17059530)) |
| H61221 | 54 | A | 一个人的伟大之处在于他能够**意味着**自己的渺小。 | Correction: 意识到 ([ref.](https://zh.hinative.com/questions/17059530)) |
| H61221 | 57 | D | 有时候，恰恰是那些带给你烦恼和不幸的人在促使**地**你不断地前进。 | Correction: 着; appears [adapted](https://www.zhihu.com/question/325135694/answer/736328246) from 很多时候，恰恰是这些带给你烦恼和不幸的人或事情在促使着你不断地前进。 |
| H61221 | 58 | C | 人一旦记住**的**事情，要几乎遗忘是不可能的；看似遗忘的事情，其实只是被锁在记忆的深处罢了。 | Correction: 了 ([ref.](https://zh.hinative.com/questions/17059530)) |
| H61221 | 60 | D | 有些网站**可以**免费申请个人主页的功能，这样，只要你将自己的信息放在网上，全世界的人都可以了解你了。 | Correction: 有 ([ref.](https://zh.hinative.com/questions/8425410)) |
| H61218 | 57 | D | **至少在**周代，饮食礼仪已形成一套相当完善的制度一直传承到现代。 | 早在 (my teacher's correction) |
| H61327 | 53 | C | 时间就像海绵里的水，**要不然**你愿意挤，总是有的。 | Correction: 只要; this is [a 鲁迅 quote](https://www.sohu.com/a/57340807_378954) |
| H61327 | 54 | B | 秦始皇陵兵马俑**凝聚**了世界各地慕名而来的**参观者**。 | Correction: 吸引……参观者 ([ref.](https://zh.hinative.com/questions/17070856)) |
| H61328 | 52 | C | **经过**显微镜，我们可以清楚地看到肉眼看不见的微生物。 | Correction: 通过 ([ref.](https://blog.daum.net/classical0123/1747)) |
| H61328 | 54 | B | 五彩缤纷的焰火在夜空中**组织**了一幅美妙无比的图案。 | Correction: 组成 ([ref.](https://blog.daum.net/classical0123/1747)) |
| H61328 | 59 | D | 花样游泳原为游泳比赛间歇时的水中表演项目，**从而**逐渐融入音乐和舞蹈，成为一项优美的水上竞技运动。 | Correction: 进而 ([ref.](https://zh.hinative.com/questions/20074086)) or 后来 ([ref.](https://blog.daum.net/classical0123/1747)); appears [adapted](https://www.ccdi.gov.cn/yaowen/202108/t20210808_247929.html) from 原为游泳比赛间歇时的水中表演项目，后来逐渐融入舞蹈和音乐，成为一项优美的水上竞技项目。 |
| H61329 | 55 | A | 智能手机**扩大**了微博等社交媒体工具的普及**速度**。 | Correction: e.g. 提高……速度 |
| H61329 | 56 | C | 有人说：“有两种东西，**即便**失去才知道可贵：一是青春，一是健康。” | Correction: 一旦; appears [adapted](https://www.wenbf.com/post/%E5%A4%B1%E5%8E%BB%E8%BF%87%E6%89%8D%E7%9F%A5%E9%81%93%E5%8F%AF%E8%B4%B5.html) from 大多数人认为，世上有两种东西，一旦失去才知道它的可贵：一是青春，一是健康。 |
| H61329 | 58 | D | 鸟类在迁徙期最容易受人工光源的干扰。它们原本是以星星定向的，城市的照明光却常常**被**它们迷失方向。 | Correction: 使; appears [adapted](https://www.thn21.com/Article/shuo/52114.html) from 鸟类在迁徙期最容易受人工光源的干扰。它们原本是以星星定向的。城市的照明光却常常使它们迷失方向。 |
| H61330 | 54 | D | 《古文观止》自问世以来，广为**遗传**，至今仍不失为一部有价值的选本。 | Correction: 传布; appears adapted from [an old civil service test question](http://www.gjgwy.org/201905/417672.html) ([answer](http://www.dwjiaoyu.cn/newsshow-64-1629-15-1.html)) |
| H61330 | 56 | C | 狮子每天要睡 20 个小时左右，**因而**它在捕食猎物时会消耗大量体力。 | Correction: 因为 [or just delete 因而] |
| H61330 | 60 | B | **当**你处于某种强烈的情绪状态**的情况**，不要急着做决定，因为此时做的决定很可能会让你在冷静时后悔。 | Error: 状态 and 情况 are redundant; should be e.g. 当……时 ([ref.](https://zh.hinative.com/questions/20088980)), 当……中 ([ref.](https://answers.echineselearning.com/questions/2014-07/19/002319383DETLRLEO.html)) |
| H61332 | 56 | A | 蔬菜要尽可能现炒现吃，**逃避**长时间保温和多次加热。 | Correction: 避免 ([ref.](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/a/39719/8099)) |
| H61332 | 57 | D | 一个人要有主见，要具备判断是非的能力，**更**不会被别人的意见所左右。 | Correction: 才 ([ref.](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/a/39719/8099)) |
| H61333 | 51 | C | 我的抽屉里堆满了旅游时买**了**各种纪念品。 | Correction: 的 ([ref.](https://blog.daum.net/classical0123/1599)) |
| H61333 | 52 | B | 这项活动的意义，在于**呈现**人们的环保意识。 | Correction: 提高 ([ref.](https://blog.daum.net/classical0123/1599)) |
| H61333 | 54 | B | 人要学会控制自己的欲望，而不应当**把**欲望所支配。 | Correction: 被 ([ref.](https://blog.daum.net/classical0123/1599)) |
| H61333 | 55 | D | 有时我们难免要对生活做出妥协，**而且**一些基本原则永远不能放弃。 | Correction: 但是 ([ref.](https://blog.daum.net/classical0123/1599)) |

Answer (score 0):

## Unwanted word(s)

| Exam | Q<sup>n</sup> | Ans. | Original snippet with error highlighted | Comments |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| H61001 | 51 | D | 婺源是**属于**南宋著名学者朱熹的故里和中国铁路之父詹天佑的家乡。 | ([ref.](https://zh.hinative.com/questions/17025909)); ([ref.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9SVR3hUWphw) ~6m20s) |
| H61003 | 56 | B | 在年降雨量少于500毫升的地区不能种树，**但**只能种草。 | Correction; delete 但 ([ref.](https://zh.hinative.com/questions/17033653)) or change 只能 to 可以 ([ref.](https://answers.echineselearning.com/questions/2017-06/28/165324010SXXDMMZG.html)) |
| H61004 | 55 | A | 台风给沿海居民的生活造成了很大的损失**严重**。 | ([ref.](https://zh.hinative.com/questions/17041574)) |
| H61004 | 56 | B |  | duplicate: H61003 Q.56 |
| H61006 | 52 | B | 你不努力学习，那怎么可能有好的成绩**是可想而知的**。 | Correction: delete 是可想而知的 ([ref.](https://zh.hinative.com/questions/17292434)) or change 怎么 to 没 ([ref.](https://zh.hinative.com/questions/17044588)), etc. |
| H61006 | 58 | B | 今天，我们去了北京郊区**的地方**，游览了很多著名的景点，如十三陵、青龙峡、黑龙潭等。 | ([ref.](https://zh.hinative.com/questions/17292434)) |
| H61007 | 53 | C | 我相信贵公司以后不但会在国内，而且会向海外**也**推广这些产品。 | ([ref.](https://zh.hinative.com/questions/17047420)); can change it to 而且也会向海外推广 ([ref.](https://www.reddit.com/r/ChineseLanguage/comments/y13uym/comment/irwjqw7/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3)) |
| H61007 | 54 | B | **由于**计算机技术的普及，为学校开展多媒体教学提供了良好的条件。 | Correction: delete 由于 ([ref.](https://zh.hinative.com/questions/17047420)); the first clause needs to be the subject, since the second clause contains the verb 提供 and object 条件 |
| H61008 | 54 | B | **由于**剪纸材料和所用的工具决定了剪纸的艺术风格。 | ([ref.](https://zh.hinative.com/questions/17049071)) |
| H61008 | 59 | A | 《绿色通道》这套系列丛书读者对象主要是**面向**高一年级的老师和学生。 | ([ref.](https://zh.hinative.com/questions/17049071)) |
| H61009 | 53 | D | 跳绳是一项很好的运动，能有效训练人们的耐力和协调力**的提高**。 | ([ref.](https://zh.hinative.com/questions/17052657)) |
| H61009 | 54 | B | 要想根除田野里的杂草，最好的方法**措施**就是在上面种上庄稼。 | Correction: 方法 or 措施, but not both ([ref.](https://zh.hinative.com/questions/17052657)) |
| H61111 | 52 | C | 他们俩是在地下通道结识的，共同的爱好使他们决定一起合作**成功**。 | ([ref.](https://zh.hinative.com/questions/17057338)) |
| H61111 | 53 | B | 在训练过程中，他为年轻队员们**做好了**带头作用。 | The verb 做 is overworked, taking on both 带头作用 and 好了; should e.g. delete 好 ([ref.](https://zh.hinative.com/questions/17057338)) |
| H61111 | 54 | D | 多读好书，就像和充满智慧的人聊天一样，可以丰富和**提高**我们的**知识**。 | Error: 提高……知识; should delete 和提高 ([ref.](https://zhidao.baidu.com/question/924358575915448659.html)) or modify ……丰富我们的知识，提高我们的认识 ([ref.](https://zhidao.baidu.com/question/1240244845074893459.html)) |
| H61111 | 59 | A | 正是这样的艰苦环境，磨炼了他的意志，使他从一个天真的孩子**阶段**成长为一个男子汉。 | ([ref.](https://zh.hinative.com/questions/17057338)) |
| H61219 | 55 | C | 他没来北京前，曾在一家省电视台**做过**一段时间的**主持娱乐节目**。 | The subject and object don't match in 做过……主持娱乐节目 (my teacher's correction); ([ref.](https://hinative.com/ko/questions/17065516) mentions 没……（之）前, but I believe this is considered grammatical despite being illogical, at least it's widely used) |
| H61219 | 56 | C | 当你用一根手指指着别人时，别忘了，**而且**三根指头指着自己。 | ([ref.](https://hinative.com/ko/questions/17065516)) |
| H61219 | 57 | C | 人的潜能是无限的，关键是要找到一个**机会**能充分发挥潜能的舞台。 | ([ref.](https://hinative.com/ko/questions/17065516)) |
| H61219 | 60 | C | 福州温泉的数量之多、水质之佳，在中国大中城市中是独一无二的，**简直**获得了“福州温泉甲东南”的美誉。 | Correction: delete 简直 or change it to 甚至 ([ref.](https://hinative.com/de/questions/10821375)) |
| H61221 | 51 | B | **能否**保持谦虚的态度，可以让我们学到更多东西。 | ([ref.](https://zh.hinative.com/questions/17059530)) |
| H61221 | 56 | D | 虽然我在报社实习了一年**的经验**，但并不是说我就会进媒体这个行业。 | ([ref.](https://zh.hinative.com/questions/17059530)) |
| H61327 | 56 | C | “鸡蛋里挑骨头”常用来**被**形容一个人无中生有，故意挑别人毛病。 | ([ref.](https://zh.hinative.com/questions/17070856)) |
| H61327 | 59 | C | 一首好的曲子往往会令我们感动得热泪盈眶，**原因**之一，就是**因为**它能勾起我们对往事的回忆。 | Correction: delete 因为 |
| H61328 | 51 | B | **有没有**坚定的信念，是成功的先决条件。 | Correction: delete 有没有 ([ref.](https://blog.daum.net/classical0123/1747)) |
| H61328 | 55 | D | 西藏温暖的阳光、巍峨的雪山、雄伟的冰川无一不是吸引游客**来**的。 | (???) ([ref.](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/q/50576/8099)) [ref.](https://www.italki.com/post/question-504642) says to delete 来; [ref.](https://blog.daum.net/classical0123/1747) says to add 特色 at the end; [ref.](https://zhidao.baidu.com/question/1366316020751247339.html) says to add 景象 at the end |
| H61328 | 58 | C | 由于大量的酒精会杀死脑神经细胞，所以长期饮酒会导致记忆力减退，还有可能引发各种疾病**的可能性**。 | (ref. [1](https://zhidao.baidu.com/question/1366316020751247339.html) [2](https://blog.daum.net/classical0123/1747)) |
| H61329 | 60 | C | 中国古代的青花瓷，绘画装饰清秀素雅，图案款识种类繁多，每个时期的款识都有鲜明的时代特征**明显**。 | Appears [adapted](https://www.xiaozhishi.net/etagid63514b0/) from 我国古代青花瓷，绘画装饰清秀素雅，瓷器底部的文字，图案款识种类繁多，各个时期的款识均有鲜明的时代特征。 |
| H61329 | 59 | A | 苏洵，北宋文学家，与其子苏轼、苏辙合称“三苏”，均被列入“唐宋八大家”**之一**。 | Error: 均 clashes with 之一; should delete 之一; appears [adapted](https://www.sohu.com/a/257698216_725961) from 苏洵，北宋文学家，与其子苏轼、苏辙并以文学著称于世，世称“三苏”，均被列入“唐宋八大家”。 |
| H61330 | 57 | C | **它是**把事件的结局先写出来，然后再按时间顺序叙述事情的经过**叫倒叙**。 | Correction: delete 它是 |
| H61330 | 58 | D | 可燃冰是海底极具价值的矿产资源，它有望**被**取代煤、石油和天然气，成为21世纪的新能源。 | Appears [adapted](http://www.cnpc.com.cn/syzs/lyhg/201312/4f64e93a9d204edf889de5469ecb0f0a.shtml) from 可燃冰有望取代煤、石油和天然气，成为21世纪的新能源 and seems to also be a [high school test question](https://m.haoskill.com/html/pP1q4lPLmZElg25a.html) |
| H61332 | 52 | B | 春天来了，到处**是呈现出**一片生机勃勃的景象。 | Error: two verbs; should be 呈现出 ([ref.](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/q/39715/8099)) |
| H61332 | 58 | C | 早在原始社会末期，人们就在石头或崖壁上刻画符号**的方法**用以记事，这就是碑的起源。 | ([ref.](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/a/39719/8099)) |
| H61332 | 59 | D | 鲜花饼是一款以云南特有的食用玫瑰花入料的酥饼，是以**凭**“花味、云南味”为特色的云南经典点心的代表。 | ([ref.](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/a/39719/8099)) |
| H61332 | 60 | B | 森林能有效地保护生物的多样性，目前地球上已知的生物一半儿以上**有**在森林中栖息繁衍的。 | Correction: change 有 to 是 ([ref.](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/a/39719/8099)) |
| H61333 | 60 | D | 海参全身的骨头多达2000万块儿，但这些骨头极小，用肉眼**从来**看不见，要在显微镜下放大几十倍甚至几百倍才能看见。 | Appears [adapted](https://fxzyw.com/html/162201373612758.html) from 海参是世界上骨头最多的动物，全身骨头多达2060多万块，只是这些骨头小得用肉眼看不见，要在显微镜下放大几十甚至几百倍才能看见。由于骨头这么小，所以我们吃的时候就不会有感觉了。 |

Comment: I did not find 太阳能设备不用燃料，安全卫生， 因为不会带来污染。  in the given reference directly. I think 不用燃料 is the reason of 不会带来污染, 不会带来污染 have no relationship with 安全卫生.

Comment: @wznmickey Thanks!  Yes, it looks like I've misinterpreted it that link---there's a logical problem.  I'll edit (I'll move it to another section).

Answer (score 0):

## Other

### Self-contradictory

The snippet contradicts itself.

| Exam | Q<sup>n</sup> | Ans. | Original snippet with error highlighted | Comments |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| H61002 | 52 | C | 已经10点了，我**估计**他今天**一定**不会来参加会议了。 | ([ref.](https://zh.hinative.com/questions/17031459)) |
| H61004 | 57 | C | 这座桥修建于公元612年至618年，到现在已有**快**1400**多**年的历史了。 | ([ref.](https://zh.hinative.com/questions/17041574)) |
| H61007 | 59 | C | 除了拥有广告设计文凭外，我还上过一个与旅游有关的课程，相信这些知识对这份工作**能有着**一定的帮助。 | Error: 能 implies potential, but 有着 implies it's currently happening; should delete 能 ([ref.](https://zhidao.baidu.com/question/247511857.html)) or change 能有着 to just 有 ([ref.](https://zh.hinative.com/questions/17047420)) |
| H61007 | 56 | C | 北京私人购买汽车的数量已经占到汽车销售总量的**将近**80%**以上**。 | ([ref.](https://zh.hinative.com/questions/17047420)) |
| H61008 | 56 | D | 昨天下班的时候，外面下起了大雨，我一直到晚上8点半**才能**回**到**家。 | Correction: either 才能回家 or 才回到家 ([ref.](https://zh.hinative.com/questions/17049071)) |
| H61110 | 53 | A | 孩子们**正在**教练的指导下学习游泳**了**。 | Error: the 正在 implies it's ongoing whereas the 了 implies it's completed; should delete the 了 ([ref.](https://zh.hinative.com/questions/17056178)) |
| H61111 | 57 | C | 别等他了，他这两天挺忙的，他今天**估计一定**不会来。 |  |
| H61327 | 51 | B | 过了一会儿，汽车**突然渐渐**地放慢了速度。 | ([ref.](https://zhidao.baidu.com/question/1494716579073791819.html?&mzl=qb_xg_3&word=)) |
| H61327 | 55 | C | 夜深人静，**想起明天**发生的一连串事情，我怎么也睡不着。 | Error: you can't remember 想起 the future; could change 明天 to 今天 ([ref.](https://zh.hinative.com/questions/20061455)) |

### Double negative

| Exam | Q<sup>n</sup> | Ans. | Original snippet with error highlighted | Comments |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| H61000 | 55 | B | 我们应该尽量**避免不犯**错误或少犯错误。 | Correction: delete the 不 ([ref.](https://qb.zuoyebang.com/xfe-question/question/5bf01a8d281ab6601417828e3b2547ab.html)) |
| H61001 | 53 | D | 为了**防止**今后**不再发生**类似的事件，有关部门及时完善了管理措施。 | Correction: delete the 不 ([ref.](https://zh.hinative.com/questions/14790177)) |
| H61002 | 53 | D |  | duplicate: H61001 Q.53 |
| H61003 | 51 | C | 为了**避免**今后**不再发生**类似事故，我们必须尽快健全安全制度。 | Correction: delete the 不 ([ref.](https://qb.zuoyebang.com/xfe-question/question/dd1cbfc7be20e783b9f28dbcb7be87e8.html)) |
| H61330 | 51 | D | 运动前的热身可以有效地**防止**人们在运动中**不受伤**。 | Correction: delete the 不 |

### Overworked object

This is where there are two sentences `S1 + V1 + O1` and `S2 + V2 + O2`, wherein `O1 = S2`, and the given 语病 sentence is `S1 + V1 + O1 + V2 + O2`.  It needs to be broken apart in some way.

| Exam | Q<sup>n</sup> | Ans. | Original snippet with error highlighted | Comments |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| H61005 | 60 | C | 胶片的发明催生了另外**一个改变人类记录方式的事物的产生**带来很大影响，那就是电影。 | (ref. [1](https://www.italki.com/post/question-162851). [2](https://zh.hinative.com/questions/17039445)) |
| H61110 | 59 | A | 调查显示，多数女性喜欢**有责任心、成熟、认真、幽默的男性**最受女性欢迎。 | ([ref.](https://zh.hinative.com/questions/17056178)) |

### Subject-verb-object misuse

| Exam | Q<sup>n</sup> | Ans. | Original snippet with error highlighted | Comments |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| H61005 | 52 | B | 书中的经验和知识对我们来说**取之不尽、用之不竭的源泉**。 | Error: no verb; should e.g. add 是 after 对我们来说 ([ref.](https://zhidao.baidu.com/question/549488831.html)) |
| H61005 | 55 | C | 有些植物的花朵因吸收金属元素而改变颜色，这也能**成为**找到地下矿藏。 | Error: missing object; [ref.](https://www.italki.com/post/question-162851) adds 的线索 at the end |
| H61333 | 57 | D | 现代医学研究表明，22时到凌晨4时是人体免疫系统、造血系统**最旺盛**。 | Error: missing object; should be e.g. 最旺盛的时候; appears [adapted](https://health.huanqiu.com/article/9CaKrnJytDl) from 现代医学研究也表明，22时到凌晨4时，是免疫系统、造血系统最旺盛的时候。 |

### No subject

The snippet omits the subject at some point.

| Exam | Q<sup>n</sup> | Ans. | Original snippet with error highlighted | Comments |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| H61000 | 53 | A | 在老师的教育下，**使**我提高了认识。 | Correction: e.g. delete 在……下 ([ref.](https://zhidao.baidu.com/question/143608556.html)) |
| H61003 | 54 | A | 通过这次活动，**使**我们开阔了眼界，增长了见识。 | Correction: e.g. delete 通过 ([ref.](https://zhidao.baidu.com/question/548042532.html)) or 使 ([ref.](https://zh.hinative.com/questions/17033653)) |
| H61009 | 55 | B | 在这些教材中，基本可以**分为**三大类:口语、阅读、写作。 | Correction: e.g. delete 在……中 ([ref.](https://zh.hinative.com/questions/17052657)) |
| H61110 | 52 | D | 是不是好的作品，可以用两个标准去衡量，一个是历史**和**一个是大众。 | Correction: delete 和; [ref.](https://hinative.com/ko/questions/17056178) also adds 这 at the start |
| H61219 | 52 | D | 人类的历史发展过程中，就**是**各种文明不断交流、融合、创新的过程。 | Correction: delete 中 ([ref.](https://zh.hinative.com/questions/17065516)) |
| H61327 | 52 | A | 这种不爱惜劳动成果，任意浪费**是**可耻的。 | Correction: add e.g. 的行为 before 是 ([ref.](https://zhidao.baidu.com/question/80169007.html)) |
| H61329 | 52 | C | 看到他在网上给我的留言后，**让**我深受鼓舞。 | Correction: e.g. delete 让 ([ref.](https://zh.hinative.com/questions/2312671)) |
| H61332 | 53 | D | 通过载人航天技术的发展水平，**体现**了一个国家的综合实力。 | Correction: e.g. delete 通过 ([ref.](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/a/39722/8099)) |

### Grammar misuse

| Exam | Q<sup>n</sup> | Ans. | Original snippet with error highlighted | Comments |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| H61000 | 52 | B | 昨天**下雨很大**，赶走了连续几天来的高温。 | Multiple errors: 下雨 is a separable verb, so we can't say 下雨很大, and the subject needs to be 雨 (not 昨天); should be 雨下得很大 ([ref.](https://zh.hinative.com/questions/12690087)) or 的大雨 ([ref.](https://www.italki.com/post/question-262714)) |
| H61002 | 51 | A | 秦始皇兵马俑是在1974年发现了。 | Error: 的 omitted from 是……的; should change 了 to 的 ([ref.](https://zh.hinative.com/questions/17031459)) |
| H61002 | 57 | B | 河水的来源**除了**地下水**之外**，**还有**雨水**也是**它的来源**之一**。 | Multiple errors. [ref.](https://zh.hinative.com/questions/17031459) gives this rewrite: 除了地下水，雨水也是河水的来源之一。 |
| H61003 | 57 | B |  | duplicate: H61002 Q.57 |
| H61003 | 53 | A | 我总是能**从父母**得到鼓励和支持。 | Error: 从[person] is incorrect; [ref.](https://zh.hinative.com/questions/16791570) changes it to 从父母那里 |
| H61004 | 51 | A | 那就是**我的理由为什么**我想提拔他。 | Correction: delete the part in bold and add 的理由 at the end (ref. [1](https://zh.hinative.com/questions/17041574) [2](https://www.italki.com/post/question-162851)) |
| H61004 | 60 | B | 在景色优美的园林中散步，有助于消除长时间工作带来的紧张和疲乏，**并且**脑力、体力得到恢复。 | Correction: 使 ([ref.](https://www.italki.com/post/question-162851)) |
| H61005 | 53 | B | 太阳能设备不用燃料，**安全卫生，因为不会带来污染**。 | [ref.](https://www.italki.com/post/question-162851) rephrases it to ……不会带来污染，所以安全卫生。 The logic surrounding 因为 is the problem here. |
| H61006 | 51 | B | **不管**大家强烈反对，他仍然坚持自己的意见。 | Error: after 不管 we describe multiple possibilities; should be e.g. 即使 ([ref.](https://zh.hinative.com/questions/17044588)); [ref.](https://zhidao.baidu.com/question/1174738233323140859.html) changed it to use 虽然……但; [ref.](https://www.reddit.com/r/ChineseLanguage/comments/y13uym/comment/irwjqw7/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3) changes 不管大家 to 不顾大家(的). |
| H61006 | 57 | B | 关于语言方面的能力，我有自信肯定能**满意贵方**。 | Error: 满意 cannot take an object ([ref.](https://pt.hinative.com/questions/17292434) explains: 满意是不及物动词); should be 让贵方满意 |
| H61009 | 57 | C | 有时候，一个人做事**比**三个人一起做一件事情做起来**十分容易**。 | Error: A比B十分容易 is incorrect; should be e.g. 更容易 ([ref.](https://zh.hinative.com/questions/17052657)) or 容易得多 |
| H61110 | 51 | C | 这件衣服**的样子不是不好看，而是颜色不好**。 | Correction: 不是样子不好看，而是颜色不好看 (importantly, 样子 comes after 不是, the same as how 颜色 comes after 而是); [ref.](https://www.italki.com/post/exercise-407177) changes it to 不是样子不好看，而是颜色不适合你 |
| H61110 | 57 | D | 我住院期间，她**无微不至**，从那时起，我就对她产生了好感。 | Error: 无微不至 is used to describe 关怀, 照顾, etc.; should be e.g. 无微不至地照顾我 ([ref.](https://zh.hinative.com/questions/17056178)) |
| H61111 | 60 | A | 一个有生活情趣的人，是能够不断发现生活中的新乐趣，并且**分享**和感染**身边其他人**。 | Multiple errors: omits the 给 in 分享给……身边其他人; could be e.g. 通过分享能感染身边的每一个人 ([ref.](https://zh.hinative.com/questions/17057338)), and 的 omitted from 是……的 (my teacher's correction) |
| H61221 | 55 | C | 大麦茶**是**将大麦炒制后再经过沸煮，喝起来有一股浓浓的麦香味。 | Error: 的 omitted from 是……的; could add e.g. 的茶 at the end of the first clause ([ref.](https://zh.hinative.com/questions/17059530)); appears [derived](https://baike.sogou.com/v27263.htm) from 大麦茶是将大麦炒制后再经过沸煮而得，有一股浓浓麦香。 |
| H61218 | 54 | A | 昨天我从火车站出来的时候，天**下了**大雨。 | Error: the 下了 implies completion; should be e.g. 下着 or 下起 (ref. [1](https://zh.hinative.com/questions/17063290) [2](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/q/50526/8099)) |
| H61327 | 57 | C | 茶树菇，**民间称为“神菇”的美誉**，是高蛋白、低脂肪的纯天然食用菌。 | Correction: should be 在民间有“神菇”的美誉 ([ref.](https://zh.hinative.com/questions/17070856)) or 在民间被称为“神菇” or even 在民间被誉为“神菇” |
| H61330 | 52 | B | 黑木耳香脆爽滑，鲜嫩可口，**是**食药兼用。 | Error: 的 omitted from 是……的; could add e.g. 的真菌 at the end ([ref.](https://zh.hinative.com/questions/20081433)) |

Comment: "这座桥修建于公元612年至618年，到现在已有快1400多年的历史了。" That's not contradictory, though.