# What's the grammar error in 西藏温暖的阳光、巍峨的雪山、雄伟的冰川无一不是吸引游客来的?

Tags: grammar

> 西藏温暖的阳光、巍峨的雪山、雄伟的冰川无一不是吸引游客**来**的。
> <sub>HSK6 H61328 Q.55</sub>

This is a HSK6 语病 ungrammatical sentence.  I can't tell what the problem is here; it seems like a [是……的 grammar structure](https://resources.allsetlearning.com/chinese/grammar/The_%22shi..._de%22_construction_for_emphasizing_details).

- [This post](https://www.italki.com/post/question-504642) says to delete 来.
- [This post](https://zhidao.baidu.com/question/1366316020751247339.html) adds 景象 at the end.
- [This post](https://blog.daum.net/classical0123/1747) adds 特色 at the end.

But there's no explanations as to what is wrong with the original.  I notice multiple webpages use similar phrasing but with 原因 at the end, such as 三峡大坝是吸引游客来的原因 ([ref.](http://www.gdshe.org/Item/12531.aspx)), 京剧的特色是吸引游客来的重要原因 ([ref.](https://www.zhihu.com/question/482837370)), so it seems like something should be added at the end, but I'm not sure why.

**Question**: 西藏温暖的阳光、巍峨的雪山、雄伟的冰川无一不是吸引游客来的

---

PS., the full question is

> - 任何事情做到恰到好处才是最好的，过和不及皆不可取。
> - “坐井观天”是指在井底看天，比喻眼光狭小,看到的有限。
> - 真正的强者，不是没有眼泪的人，而是含着眼泪依然奔跑的人。
> - 西藏温暖的阳光、巍峨的雪山、雄伟的冰川无一不是吸引游客来的。

and the given answer is 55.D.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

西藏温暖的阳光、巍峨的雪山、雄伟的冰川无一不是吸引游客来的

Quite a sneaky question.

It lays the 是....的 "trap" to lead one astray.

The 是 here is not a component of 是吸引游客来的, but a component of 无一不是, a complete idiomatic phrase in itself. It is a "double negative", meaning "none of which are not....", or in the positive, "all of which are...."

So the material part of the sentence, i.e. 无一不是吸引游客来的, therefore reads, "none of which are not a draw / an attraction to tourists"

In isolation this sentence, 无一不是吸引游客来的, appears "complete" However, when there are "reasons why" tourists are attracted in the form of 西藏温暖的阳光、巍峨的雪山、雄伟的冰川, all of which are 无一不是 the "reasons", then the "reasons", in the form of 原因 needed to be added after the end 的 to resolve the "subject / object / adjectival" structure.

If not the whole sentence 藏温暖的阳光、巍峨的雪山、雄伟的冰川无一不是吸引游客来的 is left "hanging", because it begs the question 无一不是吸引游客来的 -- 的 what?, Answer -- 的原因

Answer (score 0):

The sentence can be corrected in the similar way as what you listed, i.e.,

1. 西藏温暖的阳光、巍峨的雪山、雄伟的冰川无一不是吸引游客来的**原因**。

which might indeed be the intention of the exam. This correction is perfectly fine, but for native speakers, maybe the following is better:

2. 西藏温暖的阳光、巍峨的雪山、雄伟的冰川无一不吸引**着**游客。

since it's more concise while delivering the same meaning.

Put it another way, if this were not an exam about basic grammar, but for more advanced 修辞/写作, the first (corrected) sentence can be seen as having redundancy and needs to be (further) corrected, IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

> 西藏温暖的阳光、巍峨的雪山、雄伟的冰川无一不是吸引游客来的

- 西藏温暖的阳光、巍峨的雪山、雄伟的冰川无一不是吸引游客的 (吸引游客的 is an adjectival phrase that describes the three features
- 西藏温暖的阳光、巍峨的雪山、雄伟的冰川无一不是吸引游客来的因素 (the three listed features are counted as 'factors/ reasons that attract people to come to visit)

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't wrong for the omission because the three things can't be classified consensually. They are just commonly three things, not 景点, 原因, 特色, etc. When you classify them, you are expressing something. For example, when you use “原因”, you are telling why tourists come, the focus is slightly deflected from these things then.

“来” may be the key, but I do accept this sentense. It's not meaningless to have differences between “吸引游客的”, “吸引游客来的”, “吸引游客去的”. And as for the examination, (D) is obviously the worst.

Answer (score -2):

西藏温暖的阳光、巍峨的雪山、雄伟的冰川无一不是吸引游客来的。

- 西藏温暖的阳光、巍峨的雪山、雄伟的冰川无一不吸引游客。
- 西藏温暖的阳光、巍峨的雪山、雄伟的冰川无一**是**不吸引游客**的**。

Comment: Just so that readers do not mislead: both of these two corrections sound a little artificial/awkward, not natural like how native speakers speak.