# How did I go in my mock HSK6 exam faulty wording section?

Tags: grammar, hsk

I took a mock HSK6 exam yesterday, which I recorded to see where I went wrong.

> 51. 1. A 深秋的太平山，是人们攀登高山欣赏红叶的最佳时节。 [my answer]
>     2. B 车辆驶过整洁宽敞的大道，古朴的牌楼迎面映入眼帘。
>     3. C 网络空间急剧扩张，已经覆盖了人类社会生活的各个领域。
>     4. D 报告显示，去年中国游客量增幅超过50％，呈现明显的上升趋势。

Easy: 太平山……是……时节 is clearly wrong (I didn't even bother reading the other sentences).

> 52. 1. A 命运赋予你多少才华，就会赋予你多少责任。
>     2. B 丝绸图案的设计宗旨是把自然界的美在丝绸上进行再现。
>     3. C 这类综艺节目深受观众喜爱的原因在于其新颖的内容造成的。 [my answer]
>     4. D 曹文轩获得“国际安徒生奖”，实现了中国作家在该奖项上零的突破。

I chose C because of 原因在于……的.  I couldn't find anything I was certain is an error.

> 53. 1. A 梦想无论怎么模糊，它总潜伏在我们心底。
>     2. B 细微的洞察力和丰富的感情，是成为优秀艺术家的必要。
>     3. C 麻婆豆腐是一道川菜佳肴，由煎豆腐、牛肉沫以及辣呋酱料炒制而成。 [my answer]
>     4. D 经济学理论普遍认为，在收缩型房市泡沫影响到实体经济以前应当降息。

I chose C because it seemed awkward, but I now think the answer is D because 经济学理论 cannot 认为, only people can 认为.

> 54. 1. A 青少年学生沉迷于手机的危害应该得到引导和管理。 [my answer]
>     2. B 面对层出不穷的诈骗手段，每个人都应该要有一定的防范意识。
>     3. C 我宁愿在正确的道路上跌跌撞撞，也不愿在错误的道路上奔跑如飞。
>     4. D 食品安全部门进一步扩大了奶制品的检验范围，暂时没有发现异常情况。

I chose A because I struggled to parse the sentence, but it seems the subject is ……的危害, and it's fine.  I now think the error is 应该要有, which should be either 应该有 or 要有.

> 55. 1. A 张邦富将背包归还失主，并请失主当场清点包内钱数和物品。
>     2. B 今日起，第五频道开设“书里乾坤’’栏目，邀请名家研读经典著作。
>     3. C 部分中学拟把足球学习情况纳入学生档案，作为综合素质评价的参考。
>     4. D 当记者问她的恋爱经历时，她不但尴尬，反而大方地回应了记者的问题。 [my answer]

Easy: 不但……反而 confuses grammar structures.

> 56. 1. A 这件事情的真相可能远比你想象的更为复杂。
>     2. B 研讨过程中，应该让大家各抒己见，刻不容缓，珍惜宝贵的时间。
>     3. C 互联网时代的碎片化阅读正使我们逐渐丧失深度阅读与思考的能力。
>     4. D 交管部门制定了相关安全管理措施，以防止这类恶性交通事故再度发生。 [my answer]

I chose D, but I was wrong (I saw 防止……再度发生 and thought it was a double negative, but I was too hasty).  Honestly, I found this hard, and the only possible error I can see is that the options in B are mismatched: 刻不容缓 is urgent, but 各抒己见 and 珍惜宝贵的时间 are slow processes.

> 57. 1. A 一年来，戏剧人才培养迈出坚实步伐，青年戏剧人才队伍日益壮大。
>     2. B 只有具备较强人物塑造能力的演员，才能驾驭这些类型迥异的角色。
>     3. C 无法否认，在事业上开创一个新局面不是所有公司同仁共同努力的结果。 [my answer]
>     4. D 为了更好地传授汉字知识，学校组织了多次“让你爱上中国字’’的活动。

My answer was D because I think 结果 is the wrong word; it should be 目标.

> 58. 1. A 那位著名的画家从工匠的手里购买了价格昂贵、被视为1分宝的宣笔一支。 [my answer]
>     2. B 年轻人受网络语言的影响，忽视语言的规范性，这引起了教育工作者的忧虑。
>     3. C 每个职场新人都会欠缺工作经验，但管理者更在意的是他们对工作的投入度和专注度。
>     4. D “光盘”行动是一家非政府机构发起的公益活动，意在让人们养成节约粮食的良好习惯。

I chose A because of 宣笔一支.  I'm not sure if this is wrong, but I didn't find anything else.

> 59. 1. A 孩子们读书读得疲倦时，就会被老师带到校园东边的树林里唱歌、跳舞、做集体游戏。
>     2. B 迎面吹来的寒风使我打了个寒颤不禁，我赶紧扣上大衣扣子，快步向不远处的汽车站走去。
>     3. C 在上下五千年的沧桑岁月中，中原大地不断涌现出杰出的政治家、军事家和科学家。
>     4. D 通过阅读传记，我们可以全面了解作者的生平以及他所处的时代环境，真正走进作品，去获得独特的情感体验。 [my answer]

I chose D because at the time, it felt a bit unnatural.  But I think the answer is B, because 打了个寒颤不禁 is a 杂糅 grammar error.

> 60. 1. A 随着富有趣味的照片在网上传播，这些宠物狗逐渐成为了明星，网友称这样的狗为“汪星人”。
>     2. B 中国自行设计的北斗卫星导航系统具有覆盖范围广、受地面影响小、定位准确及时等特点。
>     3. C 如何在加快发展经济的同时，减少人口增长速度，协调人类与生态环境的关系，这是摆在一些国家面前的重大课题。 [my answer]
>     4. D 珠算“申遗”成功后，不少网友表示，珠算是中国古代的重大发明，体现了古代人民的智慧，应该加以传承并发扬光大。

I chose C because I think 课题 should be 难题; what's listed don't seem to be 课题.

I went through these carefully this morning.  I think I got 53, 54, 56, and 59 wrong, so 6/10.  I'm wondering if there's anything I missed here.

**Question**: How did I go in my mock HSK6 exam faulty wording section?

Comment: On the first question, your answer was correct, but the reason was wrong. Suggest reviewing it further.

Answer (score 2):

Here are the items that I have a different view:
53. A 梦想无论怎么模糊，它总潜伏在我们心底。
“总”should be “还是”，“仍然”， or “依然”

56. B 研讨过程中，应该让大家各抒己见，刻不容缓，珍惜宝贵的时间。
    “刻不容缓”shouldn't be used here, it means it's urgent, and of vital importance. Here the meaning of "珍惜时间“ is expressed
57. D 珠算“申遗”成功后，不少网友表示，珠算是中国古代的重大发明，体现了古代人民的智慧，应该加以传承并发扬光大。
    I'm not sure but I think it's weird to say "发扬光大“ here，because it means “使好的作风、传统等得到发展”，usually collocates with an abstract noun, “他不顾自己年老体弱，长期为一位残疾人买煤送面，这种舍己为人的精神，我们应该发扬光大。“

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer: With this kind of questions it's always easier when you know how the exam usually operates. I don't.

51. You are correct.
52. Your answer is correct, 原因在于…造成的 is redundant, plus 造成 is usually used for negative consequences, so it’s not appropriate here anyway.
53. This one is not very clear to me. 认为 can be paired with theories or “-ism”s, so it shouldn’t be a problem. The answer might be B, it’s unconventional to use 必要 as a noun in Chinese.
54. Your answer is correct. The fault here is 错误搭配，you can’t “引导危机”.
55. You are correct.
56. B does sound awkward semantically, but I believe the grammatical error lies in A. 远比…更为 is redundant, it should simply be “远比你想象的复杂”.
57. You are probably right.
58. This one is not clear to me either. 宣笔一支 shouldn't be incorrect. I can see either C or D being the answer. C because the 转折关系 signaled by “但” is questionable (but this depends on context). D because some may argue that the subject of “意在” should be “非政府机构”, not “行动”.
59. Yes, the answer is B, it should be “我不禁打了个寒颤”.
60. Unclear. 课题 can mean a problem or major task, it’s actually quite often used in similar contexts, so it’s not the error here. I find the punctuation awkward, but that probably doesn't count.

Comment: 宣笔一支 is only suitable in informal spoken Chinese (as in 老板，烧饼一个). It is incorrect when written.

Answer (score 0):

52 could be:

> 这类综艺节目深受观众喜爱的原因在于其新颖的内容

54 could be:

> 青少年学生沉迷于手机应该獲得適當的引导

56 could be:

> 研讨过程中，应该让大家在有限時間各抒己见，保留餘下的时间

58 could be:

> 每个职场新人缺乏的是工作经验，但管理者卻留意他们对工作的投入度和专注度。

59:

> 迎面吹来的寒风使我不禁打了个寒颤，我赶紧扣上大衣扣子，快步向不远处的汽车站走去。

60 could be:

> 如何在加快发展经济的同时，减少人口增长速度，协调人类与生态环境的关系，这些都是摆在国家面前的一些重大课题