# Is 观点基本 -> 基本观点 really the error in the HSK6 语病 sentence beginning 进化论的一个观点基本是...?

Tags: grammar, word-order, hsk

> 进化论的一个观点基本是：在生物进化过程中，适应自然环境的物种得以生存下来，不适应的就被淘汰，这就是所谓的“优胜劣汰，适者生存”。

This is a 语病 sentence from the HSK6 past exam H61327 (Q.60).  [Here](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/q/50538/8099) I noted how the justification was 观点基本 should be 基本观点.  But I forget why I said that (at the time, I checked lots of online sources, asked my teacher, etc.), and now I think it could be correctly interpreted using 基本 as an adverb for 是:

> 进化论的一个观点 / 基本是： ...
> One of the tenets of the theory of evolution / is basically: ...

This seems quite plausible, as there are example of 基本是 used on [YouDao](https://youdao.com/result?word=%E5%9F%BA%E6%9C%AC%E6%98%AF&lang=en) such as:

> 他们的疾病**基本是**身体上的问题造成的。
> 我觉得他**基本是**正确的。

In fact, `"观点基本是"` gets a fair number of hits on [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22%E8%A7%82%E7%82%B9%E5%9F%BA%E6%9C%AC%E6%98%AF%22).

**Question**: Is 观点基本 -> 基本观点 really the error in the HSK6 语病 sentence beginning 进化论的一个观点基本是...?

Answer (score 1):

The phrase "基本是" is commonly used as adv. before some adj. "一个观点基本是" + "what something is" does not sound natural to me.

Also, within the seemingly scientific context, "进化论的一个基本观点" is much more suitable than using weasel words like "基本是".

> 他们的疾病基本是身体上的问题造成的。
> 我觉得他基本是正确的。

These two examples are different from your original question sentence: They are "Something is + adj." instead of "Something is noun."

Answer (score 1):

I think the difference between the two is the "subject" in each sentence structure:

1. The subject is "观点":

- 进化论的一个"观点"**基本(上)是**: (解釋這個觀點) - "One viewpoint" of the evolution theory **basically is** as follows: (explanation of the particular viewpoint). Note that, to be correct, I think "一个" shall be eliminated from this sentence.

2. The subject is "一个基本观点"

- 进化论的"一个基本观点"**是**: (指出這個觀點) - "One basic viewpoint" of the evolution theory **is**: (point out the particular viewpoint). Note that this sentence can be correct if only addresses a single viewpoint out of many, otherwise "一个" shall be eliminated from this sentence.